# how can I modify the urls or models to see the images in template(404 not found)?

Tags: python, django

My appName is photo. As you can see below in models.py the SubImages(file) save on

```
'photo/static/subImages/'
```

but in works.html I cant see that subImages.
 In inspect element I see

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/works/29/photo/static/subImages/blah.jpg 404 not found,
```

And I know the subImages saved on

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/photo/static/subImages/blah.jpg.
```

What should I do in urls.py or models.py to see the subImages?

models.py

```
class SubImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey('Image', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='photo/static/subImages/',max_length=1000, null=True)

class Image(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
   file = models.ImageField(upload_to='photo/static/images/',max_length=1000, null=True)
```

works.html

```
<img src="{{subImage.file}}">
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^works/(?P<param1>\d+)/$', views.specsView, name='specsView'),
```

views.py

```
def specsView(request, param1):
    subImage_list = models.SubImage.objects.filter(image_id__exact = '29')
    return render(request, 'photo/works.html', {'subImage_list':subImage_list})
```

Comment: can you show the template code where you access the images.

Comment: Did you try using `{{ subImage.file.url }}`?

Comment: Did you tried `static/subImages/'` instead of `photo/static/subImages/'` ?

Comment: @ger.s.brett of course
 `{% for subImage in subImage_list %}
<img src="{{subImage.file}}">
{% endfor %}`

Comment: @Hybrid yes but doesn't work

Comment: @maanijou yes but doesn't work

Comment: You're passing `subImage_list` to `works.html` but you're reading `subImage`? Did you forget to include some of the code?

Comment: @maanijou `subImage_list` is a list of `subImage`s

Comment: @DrTyrsa can you help me??

Comment: @Marnchair can you help me?

Comment: @karthikr can you help me plz?

Comment: Can you find your images in corresponding folder? Do they save correctly? (I ask if your upload_to path is correct. If not, try `./static/images` instead).

Comment: @maanijou yes, images saved on corresponding folder correctly. if I change the path to static/images, a folder is created in root by the name of static...